# Browse Image and pass it to popup window

Tags: javascript, html, image, file, popup

I would like to browse an image in my HTML script and then open a popup window in which the browsed image will appear.

Right now he is opening the image in the original script. But how can I pass it to the ShowImage.html popup?

```js
function newwindow(event){
           var pop = window.open("ShowImage.html", "Image","width=200, height=100");
           document.getElementById('output');
           output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
```

```html
<label>
        Browse File
        <input id="Browse" type="file" style="display: none" checked= true onchange="newwindow(event)">
    </label>

    <img id="output"/>
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you really want to achieve... 1) is the image going to be shown on the same page or a different dialog... From what i can see, you are drawing the image on the image-element tag with the id=output which is on the same page.

Comment: Yes i want to draw the image at another page (popup window). The image will be browsed from the first page and then visualised in the appearing pop up window. In my code above the image is still at the first page. I dont know how to send it to the pop up window.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the URL parameters via `window.opener` method provided that your content is **not sensitive**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Browse').change(function(){ 

    var outputImg = document.getElementById('output');



           outputImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

    window.open("ShowImage.html?imgDetails="+outputImg.src, "Image","width=200, height=100");
});
});

//window.opener.location.href
```

This should help you.

Comment: I tried your method. He's opening the popup window. But its empty. Do i need to write a code into the html script of the popup window? What do you mean with the comment window.opener.location.href?

Comment: Using this property of window object you can access the url and hence from URL you can access the image source parameter. 
Hence window.opener.location.href is just kept for your reference to use it.

Answer (score 1):

tI used JQuery now to show the Image. Its nor really exactly what i wanted but its working quite well.

```js
function showImage(event) {
  var outputImg = document.getElementById('output');
  outputImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);

  $(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  })
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input id="Browse" type="file" onchange="showImage(event)">


<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <img id="output" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `#image.jpg`

```
var pop = window.open("NewImage.html#image.jpg", "PopupWindow","width=200, height=100");
```

So in your *NewImage.html* you'll need a script like this:

```
location.hash
```

> ## lol

You can now use this to create an image with the **hash**.

Comment: Sorry, I dont really get it. I added the #image.jpg like you said. And i added location.hash to the script of the popup window. Its not working :(

Comment: Of course it's not working! The data is in `location.hash`, now you will have to create *HTML* from *javascript* to render an `<img src="lol.jpg">` via the `location.hash`

Comment: I dont really get how he knows that the #image.jpg is the file i browsed in my <input type="file">? Can you please send me an example code of what your trying to explain to me?

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem, you already use `event.target.files[0]` so you know how to get the image, right?

Comment: Yes, i know how to get the image at the parentpage. For now im just getting the Image through the browse function and writing in into the image element with the id "output" on theparents page. However, I dont really know how to pass the image to the popup window and then open it in the popup window. To use hash seems to be a nice idea. But i dont really know how to use it properly. Im a newbe.

Comment: You can use the location.hash in the popup window `NewImage.html`. Make some test with `console.log(location.hash)` in this page.